# How to change/swap a div's background image with a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a mute button (it already has an onclick function) on a site using a div with a background image. I would like to be able to change the displayed image after clicking on it (mute), but I also need to change it back after a second click (unmute). How can this be done?

The site already uses jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want jQuery's [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) which takes multiple function arguments and calls each in turn after each click event.

```
$("#mutebutton").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('on.jpg')");
        mySoundOn();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('off.jpg')");
        mySoundOff();
    }
);
```

Comment: Does jQuery automatically give you the "url(...)" wrapper for the image URL, or is it necessary to do that in the call?  I can't remember.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! This is probably the simplest way to do this. In my case, I needed to swap the two functions, because the sound was on by default.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). You just need two CSS classes, one with each background image e.g.:

```
.mute {
  background-image:url('mute.png');
}

.unmute {
  background-image:url('unmute.png');
}
```

Then the jQuery would be (assuming you have a div named "button", with class "unmute"):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('mute');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.removeAttr()` if the background image is the only think applied inline. If not, then use `.css()` and change the path to the original background image.

```
$(this).toggle(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('style');
},
function() {
   $(this).css("backgroundImage", "url(mute_img_path)");
});
```

Comment: I think it would be better (e.g, it would work) to use `.css("backgroundImage", "url(http://whatever)")`.

Comment: There's no "src" attribute on a `<div>` element for its background image. (Oh, and if there *were*, you'd probably want to set it with ".prop()" instead of ".attr()".)

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: OP is asking specifically about changing a background image.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for that, misread the question the first time. Too early =/ Sorry OP!

Answer (score -1):

its easy

```
<div id="img-swap" />
```

where xxxxxx_Off is you image for mute

```
$(function(){
  $("#img-swap").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      $(this).css("background-image","on.jpg");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-image","off.jpg");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

this will switch image on click from off to on. you must use a pattern for images that will contain _off and _on suffix

Comment: He wants to toggle the background image of a `<div>`, not the "src" of an `<img>`.

Comment: thnx @AndrewPeacock for the clarification. i have changed it to on()